# Find 3 or more whitespaces with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

As said above, I want to find 3 or more whitespaces with regex in C#. Currently I tried:

`\s{3,}` and `[ ]{3,}` for `Somestreet 155/ EG 47`. Both didnt worked out. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your regex is looking for 3 consecutive whitespaces..

Comment: `\s{3,}` will match 3 consecutive whitespace chars. What are you trying to match?

Comment: Would you consider two consecutive whitespaces and one other whitespace a match? Or just three separate groups of whitespace?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I want to match all 3 whitespaces that exist in "Somestreet 155/ EG 47", not the consecutive.

Comment: `bool result = source.Where(c => c == ' ').Skip(2).Any();` - do we have at least 3 spaces within `source` string (not necessary in a row) (*Linq*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `\s{3,}` matches 3 or more whitespace in a row. You need for example this pattern `\s.*\s.*\s` to match a string with 3 whitespaces anywhere.

So this would match:

```
a b c d
a  b c
a   b
abc d e f
   a
a  b // ends in 1 space
   // just 3 spaces
a   // ends in 3 spaces
```

Comment: Beware that will also match three spaces alone, and even `\n\n\n`.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that should be extremely clear from my example.

Comment: Yes, but just in case... My comment was mainly aimed to the reader, especially Spennox. We don't know exactly what input he might have.

Answer (score 2):

*Linq* is an alternative way to count spaces:

```
string source = "Somestreet 155/ EG 47";

bool result = source
  .Where(c => c == ' ') // spaces only
  .Skip(2)              // skip 2 of them 
  .Any();               // do we have at least 1 more (i.e. 3d space?)
```

**Edit:** If you want not just *spaces* but *whitespaces* `Where` should be

```
   ... 
  .Where(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
   ...
```

Comment: What's the difference with `.Count(c => c == ' ') > 2`?

Comment: @Andrew: in case of *very long* string with *many* spaces `.Count(c => c == ' ') > 2` can well appear *too slow*: we first execute `Count` to find out that we have, say, `12345678` spaces and only then check if `12345678 > 2`. `Skip(2).Any()` will stop on the **3d** space found

Comment: I did some benchmark and you are right, it's much faster. As long as there's no `ToList` (or similar) after the `Where`, it won't check the whole string. If there was a `ToList`, the `Count` would be a little bit faster. ;)

Comment: And by the way, this is also much faster than the Regex alternatives. PS: I liked that 3D space. :P

Comment: @Andrew Morton: thank you! You are quite right, it should be `Where(c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))` if we want to count whitespaces, not just spaces `' '`

Answer (score 2):

You could count the whitespace matches:

```
if (Regex.Matches(yourString, @"\s+").Count >= 3) {...}
```

The `+` makes sure that consecutive matches to `\s` only count once, so `"Somestreet    155/    EG    47"` has three matches but `"Somestreet 155/    EG47"` only has two.

If the string is long, then it could take more time than necessary to get all the matches then count them. An alternative is to get one match at a time and bail out early if the required number of matches has been met:

```
static bool MatchesAtLeast(string s, Regex re, int matchCount)
{
    bool success = false;
    int startPos = 0;

    while (!success)
    {
        Match m = re.Match(s, startPos);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            matchCount--;
            success = (matchCount <= 0);
            startPos = m.Index + m.Length;
            if (startPos > s.Length - 2) { break; }
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    return success;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex re = new Regex(@"\s+");
    string s = "Somestreet  155/ EG\t47";

    Console.WriteLine(MatchesAtLeast(s, re, 3)); // outputs True
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: The approach is intersting: do we have at least `3` *chunks* of spaces, e.g. **"abcd 
   45   6"** does have `3` spaces but `2`  chunks only.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s\S*$` instead.

`\S` matches non-whitespace characters, `^` matches beginnning of a string and `$` matches end of a string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aILysv/1)

Comment: Just for the record, this is the slowest approach. The fastest one is Dmitry's.